# Disable beep of KSTAR Powercom 600VA UPS (USB identifies as MEC0003)

Tags: usb, ups

I bought a KSTAR Powercom 600VA Line Interactive UPS with USB. It works fine, but I want to disable the beep when the power is down.

When I plug the USB cable into my laptop (running Ubuntu 18.04), it seems to identify as an MEC0003 device in syslog:

```
Jun 16 11:48:50 smurfenaar kernel: [103981.169542] usb 1-3: Product: MEC0003
```

What software and configuration do I need to turn off the beep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with Network UPS Tools (NUT)

### Configuring NUT for KSTAR UPS

```
$ sudo apt install nut nut-cgi
```

Sudo edited `/etc/nut/ups.conf` to contain:

```
# Set maxretry to 3 by default, this should mitigate race with slow devices:
maxretry = 3

[kstar]
driver = nutdrv_qx
port = auto
desc = "Description of this UPS"
```

and sudo edit `/etc/nut/upsd.users`

```
[admin]
password = youradminpassword
actions = SET
instcmds = ALL
```

Finally, sudo edit `/etc/nut/nut.conf` and ensure `MODE` is set to `standalone`:

```
MODE=standalone
```

Start up the ups driver and NUT deamon:

```
$ sudo upsdrvctl start
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.4
Network UPS Tools - Generic Q* USB/Serial driver 0.28 (2.7.4)
USB communication driver 0.33
Using protocol: Q1 0.07
Can't autodetect number of battery packs [-1/13.70]
Battery runtime will not be calculated (runtimecal not set)

$ sudo systemctl start nut-server
```

### Checking beep status

To see current beep status, use the `upsc` command:

```
$ upsc kstar
Init SSL without certificate database
battery.voltage: 13.70
device.type: ups
driver.name: nutdrv_qx
...

ups.beeper.status: enabled

...
```

### Disabling beep

Use the `upscmd` command with the username and password you configured in `/etc/nut/upsd.users`:

```
$ upscmd -u admin -p admin kstar beeper.toggle
```

and we see that beep is now disabled

```
$ upscmd -u admin -p admin kstar beeper.toggle 
OK

$ upsc kstar | grep beep
Init SSL without certificate database
ups.beeper.status: disabled
```

It might take a second or 5 for upsc to reflect the status change. Voila, no more beeping when the AC is down.