# Enable NUT on KSTAR Micropower 600VA

Tags: usb, ups, nut

I have a KSTAR Micropower 600VA (USB identifies as MEC0003),
installed NUT, did the following config:

[Disable beep of KSTAR Powercom 600VA UPS (USB identifies as MEC0003)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250840/disable-beep-of-kstar-powercom-600va-ups-usb-identifies-as-mec0003#new-answer?newreg=de20ffaaef7e45c8896ea45b9fa58df3)

But the deamon is not starting:

sudo service nut-server status

```
nut-server.service - Network UPS Tools - power devices information server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nut-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2021-08-21 00:26:32 CEST; 3s ago
  Process: 3540 ExecStart=/sbin/upsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 21 00:26:32 moon-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon systemd[1]: Starting Network UPS Tools - power devices information server...
Aug 21 00:26:32 moon-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon upsd[3540]: upsd disabled, please adjust the configuration to your needs
Aug 21 00:26:32 moon-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon upsd[3540]: Then set MODE to a suitable value in /etc/nut/nut.conf to enable it
Aug 21 00:26:32 moon-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon systemd[1]: Started Network UPS Tools - power devices information server.

ups.conf:

maxretry = 5

MODE=none

[kstar]

driver = nutdrv_qx

port = auto

desc = "Description of this UPS"
```

Seems like I miss some configuration, can anybody please help? Thanks in advance, Sandor

Comment: There's a useful [reference here](https://zackreed.me/installing-nut-on-ubuntu/) about installing NUT on ubuntu which has reminded me that I haven't done other than just plug in the USB  between my 20.04 instance and my APC 1500va UPS so I'll follow your question with interest.

Comment: Check logs from the driver to see why it didn't load.  If you can't find logs, run the driver by hand and see why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

As a first it doesn't seem like the mode is set properly. Start by editing nut.conf as follows:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nut/nut.conf
```

Set the mode to standalone:

```
MODE=standalone
```

Also, remove the line `MODE=none` from your `ups.conf`!

When you're done with that you can try again with starting nut:

```
$ sudo upsdrvctl start
```

and

```
$ sudo systemctl start nut-server
```

Finally check to make sure everything works properly:

```
$ sudo systemctl status nut-server
```

You should see following:

```
● nut-server.service - Network UPS Tools - power devices information server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nut-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-01-15 07:49:02 CET; 10min ago
Process: 136052 ExecStart=/sbin/upsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 136064 (upsd)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 18903)
Memory: 1020.0K
CGroup: /system.slice/nut-server.service
             └─136064 /lib/nut/upsd

Jan 15 07:49:02 server systemd[1]: Starting Network UPS Tools - power devices information server...
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136052]: fopen /run/nut/upsd.pid: No such file or directory
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136052]: listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3493
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136052]: listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3493
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136052]: listening on ::1 port 3493
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136052]: listening on ::1 port 3493
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136052]: Connected to UPS [kstar]: nutdrv_qx-kstar
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136052]: Connected to UPS [kstar]: nutdrv_qx-kstar
Jan 15 07:49:02 server upsd[136064]: Startup successful
Jan 15 07:49:02 server systemd[1]: Started Network UPS Tools - power devices information server.
```

If that doesn't help please post the full content of your config files: `/etc/nut/ups.conf` and `/etc/nut/nut.conf`.